# How to recover when I cannot log in, and Windows recovery mode does not accept my password?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, bsod

After installing the recent windows update, I started experiencing an "Unmountable Boot Volume" crash. My system would be operating fine, then it would blue screen, restart, and then produce another blue screen with this error code.

I tried restarting a couple of times and kept experiencing the same problem.

I googled the error and an early suggestion was to remove the recent windows updates. I boot into recovery mode {the restart that is blue and has the "troubleshoot" option}, and attempted to remove the most recent quality update. I believe it is worth noting, when I attempted this, I was NOT required to click on any administrative accounts or enter any passwords. When I click to do so, it said something along the lines of unable to do so. Okay.

I look into it further and I tried following another post, and it was suggested to try booting into Diagnostic Mode. So I followed the steps and restarted my PC in Diagnostic Mode. However, I was not able to proceed past the log in screen as I was getting an error that stated "Something has happened and your PIN isn't available. click to set up". I click to set up and it looks like it's about to load until it goes back to the same screen as before I clicked. I click again and the same thing occurs. It also does not allow me to sign in by other means. I am now unable to log in to my PC via my windows account.

I retry the Recovery Mode restart. I forced shutdown twice, and at the third attempt Windows boots into recovery. This time, when I click to remove a Windows update, I'm given the option to click on an administrator account (mine) and enter a password before proceeding. Great. I enter my password, and it tells me the password is wrong. Not so great. I'm certain the password is correct. I even check by logging into my Microsoft account on my phone via a web browser. A different post suggest the recovery password could be an older password. So I try every password I can ever recall having (only a handful) and none of them work.

Oh and now, when I do go back to the log in screen and click to activate/create a new PIN, a "New User" appears under accounts. On the bottom left above my account. A new one for each time I click.

So now, I am unable to log into my PC, and I am unable to do anything in recovery mode.

How am I supposed to proceed? I want to be able to log back in. I also want to attempt to remove the most recent Windows updates to see if that fixes my crashing. I had not had any issues prior to the update, and have not made any changes physically to the PC.

Comment: My suggestion would be to enable the built-in Administrator and log into that account, you are likely having a problem since the local account is connected to a Microsoft Account and there is something seriously wrong with your installation.  This typically isn't a problem, but your limited to Diagnostic Mode, and thus the login is failing

Comment: First thing, **make a disk image**, since it may be that the storage device, SSD or HDD, is failing, and getting worse with each attempt to restart. Then you might be able to recover data. You will need imaging software, such as free Macrium Reflect, and external media, such as an eternal HDD, to hold the image.